# C++ : Different deduction of type auto between const int * and cont int &

Tags: c++, c++11

Here are the code samples.

```
a. int ii = 0;
b. const int ci = ii;
c. auto e = &ci; --> e is const int *
d. auto &f = 42; --> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘int&’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
e. const auto &g = 42 --> ok
```

Observation:
1. for clause c) the type const is automatically deduced
2. for clause d) the type const is not automatically deduced
3. for clause e) the type const has to be added manually in order for it to work.

Why type const is automatically deduced for clause c but not d?

Comment: You have a slight misunderstanding about (c): while `e` is a pointer-to-constant, it is **not** const. For example, you can modify `e` by writing `e = e+1;`.

If `e` were `const`, then its type would be `const int * const`.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is not the const-ness, but the r-value-ness.

You can't take a non-const reference to an r-value.

If you wonder what's an r-value, the original idea was something that can only be at the right side of an assignment.

To take the address of a compile-time constant the compiler first copies it, and gives you that address.  To enable that behavior, the reference must explicitly be `const`.

To complete the answer:
case

- c) the type of `ci` is `const int`, thus the type of `&ci` is address of `const int`.
- d) The type of `42` is `int`.  `auto` deduces to `int`, `f` is declared a reference to `int`, but fails to bind to r-value
- e) The type of `g` is `const int &`, which can bind to compile time constant.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the type of `42` is not `const int`, it's `int`. It's an rvalue, which means it cannot bind to an lvalue reference (unless it's a reference to `const`), but it's still of type `int`. So that's what `auto` deduces to.

If you try it with `ci` instead of `42`, you'll find it [works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/146302e26a632820):

```
auto &e = ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
auto &f = 42;
```

`42` has the type `int` so `auto &f` becomes `int &f`.  Now `42` is a compile time literal and as such it is an r-value.  We cannot bind an r-value to a reference so you get a compiler error.  When you used

```
const auto &g = 42
```

`g` is now a `const int &` and a `const &` can bind to a temporary and extends its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a small amount of confusion as to what's going on.  Your c isn't trying to deduce anything regarding `const`.  `ci` is `const int` (int which is const).  `&ci` is a `const int *` (non-const pointer to an int which is const).  The auto could not just be `int *` as then you would have broken the const contract.

As others have mentioned, for d you're trying to bind a non-const reference to an rvalue (The number '42' doesn't necessarily exist anywhere in memory, thus how could you form a reference to it... which in the future you could modify?).  For e, the compiler is now willing to put 42 somewhere in memory because you just promised that you're not going to change it.